# if you were to roll a four-sided die 100 times what is the probability that you will not roll a four?

Tags: probability, dice

I was playing d&d and using a online roller that has the option to pick how many times you rolled the die, so out of curiosity I set it to the max (100) and pressed roll about twenty times and I always got at least 20 fours so I tried four a little while and I could not figure it out so I looked it up and came here.

Comment: Perhaps more interesting, the probability of getting $20$ or more fours is about $0.90047$ and the change of this happening twenty times in a row is about $0.12285$

Comment: @bobmicbob Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

For each roll the probability to not get a 4 is $\frac34$ then for 100 rolls we have

$$p=\left(\frac34\right)^{100}\approx 3.21\cdot10^{-13}\approx 3.21\cdot10^{-11}\%$$

Answer (score 1):

If you roll a d$4$ once, the probability that you don't roll a $4$ is $3/4$.  If you roll it $100$ times, the probability that you don't roll a $4$ at any point is

$$
\left(\frac34\right)^{100} \approx 0.00000000000032072
$$

Answer (score 1):

You must roll a $1,2,3$ with probability $\frac{3}{4}$, $100$ consecutive times. By independence and multiplicity, we have

$$p=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{100}\approx 3.207\cdot10^{-13}$$

Can you use this to find the probability of getting **at least** one four in $100$ tosses?